# why pointer to char behaves differently as compared to pointersof other data types

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I have doubts regarding following statments;

```
int intvalue = 3;
int *pointInt = &intvalue;

char* p = "string";
cout << pointInt << std::endl;  // this will give memory location of intvalue which is ok.
cout << p<< std::endl; // why this will give string value  rather than memory location of where string is stored?
```

Comment: Because of overloaded operator `<<`

Comment: I edited the title; the question is about `char*`, not pointer to `char*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is an [overload of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), which assumes the `char*` is the first element of a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and prints out the whole string.

You can have a lot of fun by attempting to stream a `char*` that is *not* the first element of a null-terminated string:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  char c = 'x';
  std::cout << &c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You have an odd --- one might even say *undefined* -- notion of fun.

Comment: @JimBalter one can spend hours running that code and looking at the pretty symbols that come out...

Answer (score 3):

`char*` and `const char*` are most commonly used to point to C-style null-terminated strings. The standard I/O library takes this into account when being passed one of those types to insert from or extract into. The functions were simply designed to have this special case based on how common it is to want to print out a C-style string.

To get the pointer value, you can try casting to a different pointer type:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

keyword operator overloading - simply another method of the iostream instance `std::cout` is responsible for chars and handles that differently. The exact implementation could also yield "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << (void *) p << std::endl;
```

I expect it's because `<<` operator has a specific override for `char*` argument, to output the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is `operator<<()` overload for the type of the cout object as first parameter and type `char*` or `const char*` as second.

There are many such overloads, and you can write some too.

And the reason for this particular overload is to "print" C-style string (null-terminated array of char)